# Display none if child and parent element have the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these menus around my horizontal scrolling site.

```
 <section class="fun-stuff portfolio-cards" id="slide-1">

      <div class="nav-list">
      <button class="about">ABOUT</button>
      <button class="fun-stuff">FUN STUFF</button>
      <button class="home">HOME</button>
      <button class="professional">PROFESSIONAL</button>
      <button class="contact">CONTACT</button>
      </div>

</section
```

The goal is to filter them based if the button classes have the same class as the ones in the section. If they have the same class (in this example 'fun-stuff') then that button will display:none.

My jQuery. I feel I'm close or totally over-complicating it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var theList = $('.nav-list button');

    var i;
    for (i=0; i < theList.length; i++){
      var theButtons = '"' + theList[i].className + '"';
      var parentClassName = theList[i].closest('section').className;

  // tried this one. Was close i believe but no dice
     if(theButtons = theList[i].closest('section').hasClass('"' + theButtons + '"') ){
          // display that button as none
      }

  // tried this as well and for each button got 'no' in the console

      if( $(theList[i].closest('section') ).hasClass(theButtons) ){
        console.log('yes');
      } else {
        console.log ('no');
      }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you overdid it somewhat

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").each(function() {
    var $parent = $(this).closest("section"), // the section wrapping the button
           same = $parent.hasClass($(this).attr("class")); // parent has this button's class too
    $(this).toggle(!same); // hide if the same (show if not)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="fun-stuff portfolio-cards" id="slide-1">

  <div class="nav-list">
    <button class="about">ABOUT</button>
    <button class="fun-stuff">FUN STUFF</button>
    <button class="home">HOME</button>
    <button class="professional">PROFESSIONAL</button>
    <button class="contact">CONTACT</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

If you have more than one class on the button and you want to hide if one of them matches

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").each(function() {
    var bList = this.classList,
        parentList = $(this).closest("section")[0].classList, // the DOM element's classList
           same = [...parentList] // convert to iterable
            .filter(ele => bList.contains(ele)) // look up parent class in button classList
            .length>0; // found?
    $(this).toggle(!same);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="fun-stuff portfolio-cards" id="slide-1">

  <div class="nav-list">
    <button class="about">ABOUT</button>
    <button class="fun-stuff bla">FUN STUFF</button>
    <button class="home">HOME</button>
    <button class="professional">PROFESSIONAL</button>
    <button class="contact">CONTACT</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks, would you happen be able to explain how this works? Particularly the "same =..." then the line below it.

Comment: I’m just asking if the section has a class that Is the same as the button’s. This will need amending if you want more than one class on the button, for example using a filter

Comment: I updated my code to handle more than one class on the button

Answer (score 2):

You can do this pretty easily with vanilla Javascript:

```js
const classNames = document.getElementById("slide-1").classList;

document.querySelectorAll(".nav-list > button").forEach((el) => {
  if(classNames.contains(el.classList)){
     el.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```html
<section class="fun-stuff portfolio-cards" id="slide-1">
  <div class="nav-list">
    <button class="about">ABOUT</button>
    <button class="fun-stuff">FUN STUFF</button>
    <button class="home">HOME</button>
    <button class="professional">PROFESSIONAL</button>
    <button class="contact">CONTACT</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Edit: Done with two lines of code:

```js
const classList = document.getElementById("slide-1").classList;

document.querySelectorAll(".nav-list > button").forEach(el => el.style.display =  classList.contains(el.classList) ? "none": "initial");
```

```html
<section class="fun-stuff portfolio-cards" id="slide-1">
  <div class="nav-list">
    <button class="about">ABOUT</button>
    <button class="fun-stuff">FUN STUFF</button>
    <button class="home">HOME</button>
    <button class="professional">PROFESSIONAL</button>
    <button class="contact">CONTACT</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can turn the section classes into a regular array, then [filter](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) and [hide](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) the buttons.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var classes = $('#slide-1').attr("class").split(/\s+/);
    classes.forEach(function (cls) {
      $('.nav-list button').filter('.' + cls).hide()
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="fun-stuff portfolio-cards" id="slide-1">
      <div class="nav-list">
      <button class="about">ABOUT</button>
      <button class="fun-stuff">FUN STUFF</button>
      <button class="home">HOME</button>
      <button class="professional">PROFESSIONAL</button>
      <button class="contact">CONTACT</button>
      </div>
</section>
```